# MySql load file script and 2 tables

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables, one is an contact table like

```
ContactId BigInt  PK
Name varchar
Phone varchar
Address varchar
```

and a second table Vendor

```
CompanyName varchar
ContactId BigIn FK
```

I want to load vendors into the tables such that 
When I load vendors with a CSV it will put them in the contact table and load them into the vendor table

```
123423234, bob smith, 333-444-5555, 123 stree dr., CompanyOne
123123234, john doe, 444-333-2222, 423 SomeStreet st., Another Company
```

I kept the tables small and simple for the post, yes there is more but the key here is I need to use the ContactID from the contact table in the Vendor table. and I want to load them both from the same cvs. I know how to do this if it was just the one table but not sure with the 2 tables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do this with all SQL, or it might require/be easier with a scripting language like PHP. But here is the basic pseudo code idea.

CREATE an unnormalized table that your CSV file can fit into pretty directly (we'll call it `tempTable`). Then put the data from the CSV into there. (Pretty sure this will require some scripting).

Insert contact info into contact table:

```
INSERT INTO contact (name, phone, address) (SELECT DISTINCT name, phone, address FROM tempTable);
```

Add a contactID column to tempTable and update it with the IDs from the contacts table by JOINing:

```
UPDATE tempTable JOIN contact ON
  tempTable.name = contact.name
  AND tempTable.phone = contact.phone
  AND tempTable.address = contact.address
 SET tempTable.contactID = contact.contactID
```

Then INSERT into vendor much like the way we inserted in to contact:

```
INSERT INTO VENDOR (companyName, contactID) (SELECT company, contactID FROM tempTable);
```